# pandas shift on condition of a column isnull but it removes the first two columns

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have this problem with shifting an entire row based on a column condition if it is NaN.
if column 10 is NaN, shift the entire row 3 cells to the right.

initial dataframe:

```
   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0  2   1   12  3   2   12  4
1  6   2   4   7   NaN NaN NaN
2  4   1   4   3   6   3   2
3  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
4  3   1   3   2   1   2   6
5  5   2   6   1   NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
```

I come up with this solution, but the first two columns are gone somehow.

`df1_copy[df1_copy[10].isnull()] = df1_copy[df1_copy[10].isnull()].shift(3, axis=1)`

Result:

```
   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0  2   1   12  3   2   12  4
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4   7
2  4   1   4   3   6   3   2
3  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
4  3   1   3   2   1   2   6
5  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6   1
6  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
```

Expected:

```
   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0  2   1   12  3   2   12  4
1  NaN NaN NaN 6   2   4   7
2  4   1   4   3   6   3   2
3  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
4  3   1   3   2   1   2   6
5  NaN NaN NaN 5   2   6   1
6  NaN NaN NaN 4   5   3   2
```

Although I tried a similar method for other conditions before this and it's working, it doesn't seem to apply to this one. any help would be so much appreciated, thank you.
[here is the csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jhg3m_3DRLm4Geodd2tH_7t_hd8BMyEg/view)

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. Your code creates the expected result.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes, I used this same method for other conditional shifts as well. but for some reason, only at this line doesn't work. I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out I was using Pandas version that is too old and it has a bug in the shift function, I come up with this workaround. Although it's not elegant it works. Hopefully, someone can provide something better.
I ended up just rearranging the order of the columns.

```
df_shift3 = df1_copy1.loc[df1_copy1.loc[:,10].isnull()][[10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
df_shift3.columns = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
df1_copy1[df1_copy1.loc[:,10].isnull()] = df_shift3
```